# PHP CodeIgniter Framework - Does Query Builder count as a prepare() and bind_param() and how to store form post data into Query Builder array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm not finding much documentation-wise beyond some sources saying Query Builder statements are prepared, and others saying they are but not bound, then some saying they are bound etc. A solid answer would be much appreciated.

Furthermore, if I wanted to have my form data passed through into an array that I'm storing in my database, how should my following code be modified?

```
$user_first = $this->input->post('user_first');
$data['user_first'] = $user_first;
//this above code works fine if I want to store each part of the form
//in the array individually

$data = array(
    'user_first' => 'My title' 
    //How can I get 'user_first' to => $user_first?
);

$this->pdo->insert('users', $data);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question in your code because `$data['user_first'] = $user_first;` and `$data = array( 'user_first' => $user_first;);` produce exactly same array.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways

```
//adding name by name to an array
$data = array('user_first' => $this->input->post('user_first'));

adding the entire post array
//as u have the same "name" in the form than the array u are sending to the db insert method
$data = $this->input->post();
//in short $this->input->post() is $_POST array, but cleaned 

//or getting the values from $_POST
$data = array('user_first' => $_POST['user_first']);
```

Hope my answer helps u.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends to a large extent on what "prepared" means. "Binding" can be accomplished in a way very much like PDO. However, there are no methods that correspond to `PDOStatement::bindColumn`, `PDOStatement::bindParam`, or `PDOStatement::bindValue`.

The most direct equivalent to `PDO::prepare()` with "binding" would be as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

The `?` placeholders are replaced with the values in the array in the order they appear in the array. The input values will be escaped. The `query()` method does not support the PDO sytax of `:name` as a placeholder. (CI documentation on [Query Binding](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings).)

In general the various Query Builder methods combine to achieve the same overall effect as `PDO::prepare()` and `PDOStatement::execute()`.

The functionality of `PDOStatement` methods to retrieve queried data (e.g. execute(), fetch(), etc.) are accomplished by calls to CI database methods for "[Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#generating-query-results)".

Assuming the three input from my example above have been posted by a  here's how I would accomplish inserting them in a table

```
$data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
$data['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
$data['author'] = $this->input->post('author');

$this->db-insert('some_table', $data);
```

If the  element names are an exact match for the table column names and we know only those inputs will be posted the above could be simplified to

```
$this->db-insert('some_table', $this->input->post());
```